# How to show spinning progress dialogue with using separate Async Task Class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

In my app, i'm reading text files from web server using Async Tasking from a separate class because it is used in many activities, so i've made a dedicated class.
I'm trying to show a spinning progress dialogue but it is giving me error when i put the code in Async Tasking class.

here is my cod for Async Task Class

```
public class Utilssss extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Context         mContext;
    private ProgressDialog  pdia;

    // constructor
    public Utilssss(Context activityContext) {
        mContext = activityContext;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        pdia.setMessage("Loading...");
        pdia.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        return GetLinkss(url[0]);

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Toast.makeText(mContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pdia.dismiss();
    }

    private String GetLinkss(String url) {

        // your stuff
        String StringBuffer = "";
        String stringText = "";
        try {
            URL link = new URL(url);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));

            while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringText += StringBuffer;
            }
            bufferReader.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringText;
    }

}
```

Code how i'm accessing this class

```
public void urdu(View view) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        String fileexist = null;

        fileexist = new Utilssss(getBaseContext()).execute("http://192.168.1.2/eWorldLiterature/urdu/index.txt").get();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), fileexist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // if (fileexist != 229) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainPage.class);
        i.putExtra(LANGUAGE, "urdu");
        startActivity(i);
```

Here is the LogCat results.

```
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    ... 12 more
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at md.literature.imranseries.Utilssss.onPreExecute(Utilssss.java:35)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    at md.literature.imranseries.Selection.urdu(Selection.java:65)
12-05 00:38:06.266: E/AndroidRuntime(28766):    ... 14 more
```

Just one more thing i want to ask. Sorry to bother you guys again..
Here is the thing, one of my activity relies on the results of Asynctask and should no proceed unless the task is completed, but this is not happening, here is a sample piece of code which proves it.

```
        final Context context = this;
        new Utils(context, new Utils.UtilsCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(String lstr) {
//              lstr = string;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Now Raeading" + Novelselected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).execute(ulti_link + "/" + Novelselected.replace(" ", "%20") + ".txt");

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Now Raeading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

in the above code, the following Toast appears before the Toast within the AsyncTAsk appears, The question is, how can i pause my main thread to wait for the AsyncTAsk to complete. 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have tried using help from previously posted threads but they're all for using progress dialogue while using AsyncTask in activity class.

Comment: please post the stack trace

Comment: How do you set the mContext in the Utils class? It should be an Activity context and not an Application one..

Comment: @Cata beat me to it. You are passing the `Application` `Context` to the `Dialog` constructor.

Comment: @Cata i'm new to android and java but without attempting to show the progress dialogue, the utilss class works just fine.

Comment: That is whay I am telling you this.. to create UI components, you need an activity context, for other stuff you can use application context :)

Comment: what should  i give it in context fiend then ??

Comment: i'll read it. but for now is there some solution to this problem? i'm passing the BaseContext to AsyncTask function in the activity class, it works fine but without dialogue code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides using the correct `Context` you must not use `AsyncTask#get()`. Never. It blocks the Ui thread until the result is available and you can not show a progress dialog during that time then because you are already waiting for the result.

If you want to use an AsyncTask from a different class add a callback mechanism of your own.

```
public class Utilssss extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /** Implement this somewhere to get the result */
    public interface UtilssssCallback {
        void onResult(String string);
    }

    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog pdia;

    private UtilssssCallback mListener;

    // constructor
    public Utilssss(Context activityContext, UtilssssCallback listener) {
        mContext = activityContext;
        mListener = listener; // save callback
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pdia.dismiss();
        mListener.onResult(result);
    }

    // rest omitted since unchanged

}
```

And inside your `Activity`

```
public void urdu(View view) {
    final Context context = this;
    new Utilssss(context, new Utilssss.UtilssssCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(String string) {
            Toast.makeText(context, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainPage.class);
            i.putExtra(LANGUAGE, "urdu");
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }).execute("http://192.168.1.2/eWorldLiterature/urdu/index.txt");
}
```

Note that the code inside `onResult` is executed way after the program flow has already left the `urdu(View view)` method.

---

Alternatively to implementing the callback as an anonymous inner class (`new UtilssssCallback(){...}`) you could also let the `Activity` implement the interface and make it a method. Doing it that way looks less confusing but is essentially the same.

```
public class TheActivity extends FragmentActivity implements UtilssssCallback {

    public void urdu(View view) {
        // those two are not necessary but help make it obvious what parameters we have
        Context context = this;
        UtilssssCallback callback = this; // the class implements that
        new Utilssss(context, callback).execute("http://192.168.1.2/eWorldLiterature/urdu/index.txt");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(String string) {
        Toast.makeText(context, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

....
```

Comment: Thanks @zapl for this nice answer but there is one problem when i use it. i'm unable to take the string variable out from that method. i need to use it in other methods as well.. how can i do that??

Comment: public void onResult(String string) {
            Toast.makeText(context, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            
 
        }   This string variable that is output from the async task class

Comment: @M00N15 you can either call the methods with the string as parameter (like you call the `Toast` methods) and / or store it in a variable (e.g. like you store `mContext` but inside the Activity) so other places can access it.

Comment: You can not make the ui thread wait. The program flow in the main thread must continue. After you invoke the `execute` method the next thing that happens is that you show a toast (the asnytask will during that time start do work in parallel). Code you write after the asynctask will therefore happen immediately and code you write into / call from the `onResult` callback will happen in the future.

Comment: @M00N15 added a bit to the answer that looks a bit less confusing.

Comment: Thanks @azpl how can i make the UI thread wait till the AsyncTask is completed?

Comment: If you want to write a good app you have to write your code in a way that does not require waiting. `AsyncTask#get()` does that. And avoiding that was the whole point of writing that answer. All you need to do is to do whatever you need from `onResult`. Like `onClick` with buttons where you can't wait for it to happen because you don't even know whether the user will press your button.

Comment: oh.. now i get it... i must change the loading sequence that specific activity. Thanks again @zapl

Comment: i put my code in the OnpostExecute method and now no NullpointerException, everything working just fine.. bundle of thanks

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read [this](http://t.co/9R0bPWiKc5) explanation about the different types of `Context` `Android` has. There are some instances of `Context` that do not allow you to do certain things that other `Context` instances do (i.e. `Service` is a `Context` that doesn't allow layout inflation).

In your case you are passing the `Application` `Context` to the `AsyncTask` constructor, and subsequently to the `Dialog`. You should use an `Activity` `Context` instead.

Since you are calling the `AsyncTask` from an `Activity` and `Activity` extends from `Context` you can use the keyword `this` in the `AsyncTask` instantiation like Cata said.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two things:

1. Use a `WeakReference` when passing a context to an `AsyncTask`
2. Call a method on your `Activity` to start and stop your progress dialog

Something like this:

```
public class ProgressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity;

    public ProgressAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
        weakActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
        ((MainActivity) activity).showProgressDialog(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Color> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
        ((MainActivity) activity).showProgressDialog(false);
    }
```

In your MainActivity you implement the method `showProgressDialog(boolean show)`.

And as Emmanuel pointed out you should most likely pass an `Activity`'s context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fileexist = new Utilssss(this).execute("http://192.168.1.2/eWorldLiterature/urdu/index.txt").get();
```

Where "this" should be the Activity and assumming that the parameter represents the mContext on the Utilssssclass side :).

And also pay attention to Emmanuel's answer too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked and yes i feel i need to know about this context thing in more detail.. Thumbs up for u guys.